# Difference between "von ... ab" and "von ... an"?

Tags: preposition

The question is clear, I don't see what is the difference between "von etwas ab" and "von etwas an"; can someone explain the difference ?

Comment: As ironic as it may sound, I fail to see the clarity and thus am voting *unclear*.

Comment: Please give us more context. give some examples please.

Comment: it's me who needs examples to understand, I'm looking for examples and explanations, I can easily find examples in the web, but without any further explanation. I need to know when to use the former form and when to use the later form ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you say "von ... ab" or "von ... an" is largely a question of regional or personal habit. In most situations both are equivalent. Exceptions occur when it's really a shortened form of some other expression, like the colloquial "davon mal ab" which is short for "davon einmal abgesehen".

Answer (score 5):

Here's one difference: if you're referring to time, you can only say "von dann an". If you're referring to somebody or something leaving some place, you can only say "von dort ab". Example: "Von Morgen an fährt der Zug vom Hauptbahnhof ab." Starting tomorrow, the train will leave from the central station.

Comment: QUOTE: *referring to time, you can only say "von dann an"* - Nun, ***'Von da ab hat er nie mehr wieder gelogen'*** - klingt auch nicht ganz un-deutsch -> abgeleitet von ***'Ab diesem Zeitpunkt...'*** ;-)

Comment: QUOTE: referring to place, you can only say "von dort ab" - Was ist mit ***'Gehe links an der alten Mühle vorbei und von dort an gehst du dann immer gerade aus weiter...'*** -> abgeleitet von ***'voran gehen/ weiter gehen...'*** ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Von Hamburg ab  gab es  viel Verkehr.

Vom 1. Januar an.

Von..ab : for space
Von ..an: for time

I took this from a grammar book.

I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).